# Is there any way to change the product description and additional information of configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, product-attribute

Is there any way to change the product description and additional information of configurable products in view page based on weight selected

Answer (score 0):

In catalog/product/view/description.phtml file , you can put condition according to weight it will display value of description.

Comment: What about the attribute values?

Comment: you can display attribute value without any problem .